# Can I block vim from saving a file that isn't validated using an outside tool?

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to make the write ":w" command perform a forced validation for certain file types.

My use case is that I want to prevent small typos and idention errors in python source code. So VIM should not even allow me to save a file with errors.

I can run "python -m py_compile `filename`" on a file to see if it compiles. 
This command returns nothing, if all is well, otherwise and error message like
"Sorry: IndentationError: expected an indented block (hello.py, line 2)"
Alas this requires me to save the file "`filename`, which I only want done if it passes.

So I'd need to automate these steps:

- save the current file with a temporary filename,
  like `filename.insert_uuid_here.py`
- run "python -m py_compile *filename.insert_uuid_here.py*

on success:

- remove both the *filename.insert_uuid_here.py* and the
  *__python_cache__/filename.insert_uuid_here.py* file.
- allow save

on fail:

- remove the `filename.insert_uuid_here.py`
- display error from compile attempt

Is this something, that's possible?

How could I link this to any ":w" attempt to write a python file?

Comment: Might be possible using a custom `BufWriteCmd` autocommand. I would however not recommend doing that.

Comment: It might be a better approach to allow writing while linting on save, but automate the checks to block at the build or deploy phase.

Comment: Does the python command follow basic shell command execution conventions? Specifically does it optionally allow input via stdin rather than a file and does it return 0 when input is clean and non-zero otherwise? If both of these are true I have a function for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) to asynchronously lint (i.e. check for style/syntax errors) while you type. This will not prevent vim from saving the buffer when you instruct it to do so but that might be what actually you need/want.